# Source file is not available in Firefox for Ajax request

Tags: javascript, ajax, eclipse, firefox

I am working through a tutorial on `Ajax` and the following code from the tutorial works fine and I can examine it with the `Firefox` debugger.

```
for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open('GET', '/CromerrWeb/javascript/data.txt', false);
    request.send();
    if (request.status===200) {
        console.log(request);
        document.writeln(request.responseText);
    }   
}
```

However, when the tutorial changes it to asynchronous with the code below, the "Hello World" text prints out but the browser's spinning circle indicating it is busy keeps spinning and when I try to look at the code in the `Firefox` debugger it says this page has no source code.

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('GET', '/CromerrWeb/javascript/data.txt');
request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if ((request.readyState===4) && (request.status===200)) {
        console.log(request);
        document.writeln(request.responseText);
    }
}
request.send();
```

When I run the code in `Chrome`, I don't get the spinning busy circle and when I open the developer tools the `index.jsp` file which calls the `javascript` code shows up as empty but I can look at the `script.js` file which is where the `javascript` code is located.  Is this normal behavior for `Ajax` or do I have something set up incorrectly?  I am running the code in a `RAD 8.5` `Web Project` on an `IBM Websphere 7.0` server.  My project structure is show below.
[image]

Comment: You tagged this with JQuery. You are not using JQuery for this function altough it would make this a lot easier. You want an answer in JQuery or plain javascript?

Comment: Sorry for the wrong tag.  The tutorial used plain javascript so that is what I used.  I need to make sure this simple code is working correctly before I try to follow the rest of the tutorial and since it is using plain javascript that is what I need the answer in.